# Split Character String at Underscore Using scan() Function in R - strsplit() vs. scan() Comparison

Tags: r, string, function, character

I've noticed that the functions strsplit() and scan() handle underscores differently, and I'm wondering why this is the case.

Please consider the following example code:

```
x1 <- "string split"

strsplit(x1, " ")[[1]]
# [1] "string" "split" 

scan(text = x1, what = " ")
# [1] "string" "split"
```

The outputs of strsplit and scan are the same when using " " as a separator.

However, when I use "_" as a separator, the output is different:

```
x2 <- "string_split"

strsplit(x2, "_")[[1]]
# [1] "string" "split" 

scan(text = x2, what = "_")
# [1] "string_split"
```

Why is the output of strsplit and scan different when using underscores as a separator?

Comment: `what` is not a separator, but rather should be the class of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the argument `what` is not the separator but rather the data type. IN your case, you have character:

```
scan(text=x2, what = character(), sep='_', quiet = TRUE)
[1] "string" "split"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! Could you explain why scan() splits the character string when using what = " " in the first example?

Comment: @JoachimSchork because what  can take the type of the elements in the argument. In this case, the `typeof(' ')` is character

Comment: @JoachimSchork YOu could try `scan(text = '1 2 3', what = 'numeric')` and it will return a character vector instead of numeric. while `scan(text = '1 2 3', what = 2)` will return numeric. Hope this helps